# Mongoose model is not added as a new document unless I give it a unique constraint

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a few models which I need to work with. However, the model won't be added as a document in a collection unless there is a unique attribute in the schema. This happens in my localhost mongo and in mongo atlas.

Every model with a property who has a unique constraint gets added the normal way. Every model without will not be added.

When the code is written as this everything works fine:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema ({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "firstName is required"]
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "lastName is required"]
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email is required"],
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "password is required"]

  },
  appartments: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "appartments"
  }],
})
```

When the email index property gets commented out, the document will not appear:

```
 email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email is required"]
    //index: { unique: true }
  },
```

I want to add the model as a document without setting a unique constraint in every model.

Comment: Make sure that mongoose existing the relevant folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm back and figured it out!

Apparently, a model does not get added as a document until you create it from code. Because the user schema already has an index added from code it gets created. So to make your model visible as a collection you need to do something like this:

```
Apartment.create({title: "My Apartment"})
.then(apartment => {
  console.log("The apartment model is now visible with entry: " + apartment);
}).catch((error) => next(new ApiError(error, 400)))
```

Comment: Which is kind of strange because it would be nice to be able to add an entry via the MongoDB Compass application of web interface of Atlas before adding an entry in the code.